# Why is my css code not working with html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

When I open the html code with "Open with Live Server", it does not include my css code.
What did I miss? What did I do wrong?
How do I make my css code work with html?

Screenshots:
[This is my css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0QhT.png)
[This is my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPR2Q.png)

I followed the tutorial "CSS Tutorial - Full Course for Beginners"
I followed what he was doing but it seems I got it wrong. I did the whole thing over again but still not working.

```css
p {
  font-size: 64px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<IDOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link ref="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head> 

<body>
  <p>I'm currently learning CSS!</p>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It's `rel="stylesheet"` not `ref="stylesheet"`, in the `<link />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in your html it should be `rel=` not `ref=`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

#1 Rule: always first check for typos before thinking that something isn't working functionally.

Having the attention to detail to observe and detect your typos is very important if you want to learn to code (there wasn't that much to sift through in this case, you should have been able to see it)

Also, we understand because you're new, but next time paste all your code with proper formatting instead of links to images - it's much easier for us to help you if we are at least able to work with text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll pay more attention and recheck the code. Also I'll paste my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the css file in a separate page then you have to use link tag and link it with the html in the head tag enter code here

Here is the syntax:

```
<head    
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="mystyle.cs>
</head>
```